# Submonoid: Identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

There's a common mistake appearing in quite many books in definitions and proofs as well; now my idea is maybe you can safe the day:
Imagine you're having a monoid and a subset being closed under the binary operation inherited from the monoid. Moreover, let it contain an element which looks as an identity element when acting on the subset but being not the identity of the monoid.

For example:
$M:=(\mathcal{M}(2,2; \mathbb{K}),\cdot),\quad N:=(\{\text{all matrices with all but the first entry zero}\},\cdot)$
Then:
$N\leq M\text{(as submonoid)}$
But:
$\mathbb{1}_N\neq \mathbb{1}_M$

My question/idea is now: It should be possible to find an isomorphism *in general* some submonoid containing the original identity, i.e.:

$N\cong N'\leq M\text{ with }\mathbb{1}_{N'}=\mathbb{1}_M$

...can you proof this?

Comment: This is not always possible. Are you asking for general monoid M and subsemigroup N that contains an identity, or just for this particular pair of monoids of matrices?

Comment: If you are referring to this particular case, then yes, the mapping you are looking for is $f$, which sends each matrix $\left[\begin{array}{cc} a & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{array} \right]$ to $\left[\begin{array}{cc} a & 0 \\ 0 & a\end{array} \right]$. The general case, as Jack Schmidt pointed out, is not true.

Comment: @JackSchmidt: Ooh ...do u know some counterexample?

Comment: @user49685: ...yeah, I had this isomorphism in mind - but in general not true?! =/ ...do u know some counterexample?

Comment: A ring example: $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ has four sub-rngs: they haves orders 1, 2, 3, and 6. All of the sub-rngs have their own identity (possibly coinciding with 0), but only the one of order 6 contains the "one true identity". It's multiplicative monoid is not an example though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No,** it is not always possible.

If you know partial permutations, there is an easy counterexample: Let $M$ be generated by $(1,2,3)(4)(5)$ and $(4,5)$ and let $N$ be generated by $(4,5)$. Then $M$ has 5 elements: $(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)$, $(1,2,3)(4)(5)$, $(1,3,2)(4)(5)$, $(4)(5)$, and $(4,5)$. $M$ contains only two subgroups (subsemigroups that happen to be groups, they can have different identities and inverses): $N=\{ (4)(5), (4,5) \}$ and $N'=\{ (1)(2)(3)(4)(5), (1,2,3)(4)(5), (1,3,2)(4)(5) \}$. Clearly $N \not\cong N'$ since the former has two elements and the latter has three elements. Also $N'$ is the only one that contains $\mathbb{1}_M = (1)(2)(3)(4)(5)$, since $\mathbb{1}_N = (4)(5)$.

Partial perms are fairly easy to understand: they are bijections (rather than self-bijections). The ones in $M$ are even easier to understand, they are self-bijections but of different sets (either $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ or $\{4,5\}$). Composition is done in the usual way, the product of $f$ and $g$ is defined on the largest subset for which the composition makes sense. $(1,2,3)(4)(5) \cdot (4,5) = (4,5)$ since $(4,5)$ doesn't know what to do with $1$, $2$, or $3$.

They produce nice monoids known as inverse monoids and are fairly group like once you understand idempotents (elements $\mathbb{1}_N$ for subsemigroups of $M$ that happen to be monoids).

Here is the matrix representation:
$$M = \left\langle 
\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right],
\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]
\right\rangle, \quad N= \left\langle
\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]
\right\rangle$$

Then listed explicitly:
$$M=\left\{
\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right],
\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right],
\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right],
\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right],
\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]
\right\}$$
$$M=\{(4,5),(4)(5),(1,3,2)(4)(5),(1,2,3)(4)(5),(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)\}$$

Comment: I also listed all 5 elements out and matched them with the partial perm notation, in case matrices are better.

Comment: They are the same thing as permutation matrices except the numbers not mentioned are 0s. $M$ is particularly nice in that if a number isn't mentioned in the domain, it isn't in the range, so the matrices are direct sums of 0 matrices and permutation matrices. In general a partial perm matrix is a matrix with at most one one per row and column, all other entries 0.

Comment: Got it =) thanks!!!