# Why is it important for a group to be closed under an operation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In my undergrad group theory course, we have seen a lot of groups that are closed under a certain operation. I've also noticed a group now myself in my probability theory course with regards to sigma-fields. My question is why is this property of being closed important? What if a group is not closed? What is the implication of that? I know how to go about proving a particular group is closed but I cannot see the intuition behind it. Can anyone clear this up for me please.

Comment: If it was not closed, then what would you mean when you write the product? Where would that product "live"?

Comment: So it is just to make sure that whenever the operation is applied, we get back an element which is in the group? Is it really as simple as that? Nothing more?

Comment: Indeed. Note that many people will not even mention the word closed when defining a group (this is already included in the definition of what an operation is). Being closed under an operation does not become important until you take a subset (since then this could fail).

Comment: Can you give me an example of that failure when taking a subset please?

Comment: The integers are a group under addition.  What about the subset $\{z \in \mathbb{Z} \, | \, z = 1 \mod 3 \}$ -- is that a subgroup?  Turns out that it isn't, because it's not closed under addition: $1 + 4 = 5$, and $5 \ne 1 \mod 3$.

Comment: Note that the word "operation" is a vague (non-mathematical) term. Everything becomes clear when you define "operation" mathematically as a "mapping" from $G\times G\to G$, where $G$ is the group, now there is no question of closure (since it is already there in the definition of a "mapping").

Comment: @IftikharKhan The set of permutations of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ with odd parity is not "closed".

Comment: @pritam ...*binary* operation...

Answer (score 4):

By definition a group is a set $G$ and a map $G \times G \rightarrow G$ such that (...).

So it makes no sense in this context to say "a group is closed" under the operation, this is automatically true. There is no group that "is not closed".

If you have a set $X$ and a set $Y$ such that $X \subseteq Y$ and you can find some operation $p:X \times X  \rightarrow Y$, then $(X,p)$ might be a group or not. If you think this "operation" can be used to define a group $(X,p)$ then of course you must prove that $p(x,y) \in X$ for all $x,y$. If this is false, then the group axioms make no sense, there is no reason to check them at all.

Answer (score 2):

The essential feature of a group is that it describes a notion of symmetry: transformations of space that somehow don't change the figure of interest. If $f$ and $g$ both leave something alone, then so does $f \circ g$, so symmetry is automatically closed.

A variation on a group is called an [inverse monoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_semigroup), and its essential feature is a notion of partial symmetry: transformations of space that somehow don't change *part* of the figure of interest. If $f$ and $g$ both leave the same thing alone, then so does $f\circ g$, but the portion that $f$ leaves alone versus the portion that $g$ leaves alone may differ, and then the portion that $f \circ g$ leaves alone is usually smaller. Inverse monoids have many features that groups have, but simple things like [Lagrange's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_theorem_(group_theory)) fail to hold (because “cosets” can have different sizes, because we no longer have full symmetry amongst cosets, only partial; you can see how things can go wrong in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/651981/submonoid-identity/652030#652030) which has a fairly concrete inverse monoid example).

The relation to your question is an inconvenient way of defining inverse monoids: a collection of bijections with composition only defined when the range of the first matches the domain of the second. This version is called an inductive groupoid (or “[category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory) containing only isomorphisms”).

Until one understands full symmetry, that is groups, it is probably too difficult to say anything interesting about partial symmetry, inverse monoids.

Comment: You lost me on the monoid stuff. But you did raise another one of my questions regarding group theory. I keep hearing that group theory is related to symmetry. But I can't see that. If we take the group of integers closed on addition, where is the symmetry there? 1 + 2 = 3. I don't see it. Or does it apply to only certain groups?

Comment: Integers are many things, but as a group they describe the symmetry of the eternal winter rabbit. The EWR has been hopping in the snow since before time began, and will continue hopping long after it has ended. The integers describe the symmetry of the footprints left in the snow. 1 + 2 = 3 means that if you hop once and then hop a double, that is the same as hopping a triple. In symbols, one takes space to be $\mathbb{R}^1$ and the figure to be the zeros of the $\sin(x)$ function, and $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ is the symmetry $x \mapsto x + \pi n$ (where $\pi$ is the natural stride of the EWR).

Comment: It is also known as "Hop" symmetry when described as a Frieze group: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683734/the-path-to-understanding-frieze-groups

Answer (score 0):

As it's already been said in the comments: You want the group operation to be a well defined mapping. I will try to illustrate a bit, why:

Consider $\left(\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{0\right\},\cdot\right)$, the complex plane without zero and multiplication as group operation. Surely this is a group. Another group would be $\left\{x\in\mathbb{C}:\left|x\right|=1\right\}$ with the same multiplication. This is due to the facts that $\left|x\cdot y\right|=\left|x\right|\cdot\left|y\right\|=1$ and $\left|\frac{1}{x}\right|=\frac{1}{\left|x\right|}=1$ for $\left|x\right|=\left|y\right|=1$.

In practice you often choose the set of a group according to certain properties wich you might use to prove other properties, for instance, if we consider $\left(\left\{x\in\mathbb{C}:\left|x\right|=1\right\},\cdot\right)$ again, we can see that the group operates bounded, even non-expansively on $\mathbb{C}$, which are very useful properties in some cases.

If you would for instance take $\left(\left\{x\in\mathbb{C}:\frac{1}{2}\leq\left|x\right|\leq2\right\},\cdot\right)$ you would still have that the inverse of each element is a member of the set, you can also easily see that the "group" operates bounded on $\mathbb{C}$, that means $\forall y\in\mathbb{C}, \forall \frac{1}{2}\leq\left|x\right|\leq2$ you have that $\left|xy\right|\leq2\left|y\right|$ but if you iteratively apply a sequence of "group" operations $x_{1},...,x_{n}$ on $y\in\mathbb{C}$ you cannot say that $\left|x_{1}...x_{n}y\right|\leq2\left|y\right|$. This is because you do not have that $x_{1}\cdot...\cdot x_{n}$ is a member of your "group".

I hope that helps :)